# Google chrome and other programs doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, command-line, google-chrome, system, atom

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. 
 And I have some programs like "**Atom, Brackets and Google chrome**..." doesn't work. And when I opening one of then it doesn't open and sometimes I showing report problem form then nothing happens.
 also When I type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

in terminal I see this error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

really I tired of trying to solve that
How I can fix it please?

sorry for my language.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try changing the server under **settings** --> **software & updates**

Comment: @Nuwan
My system has a problem also with chosen an another server update